# How to know how many threads created by IIS for each worker process

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

How to know how many threads created by IIS for each worker process.

If my concurrent users are 100 and each user may send 30-40 API calls through the web page. Is IIS default settings are sufficient to handle with the load without any wait/queue time or DO I need to increase the Threads Per Processor Limit.

I have 8 core process machine on which my web app is deployed.

Comment: If 100 users send 30 per user a't the same time. IIS won't handle 3000 requests at the same time. Each request occupy at least one thread inside IIS and each IIS worker process can have 5000 max threads. However, IIS queue length,max connection limit the concurrent request. So some request will be blocked and some request will queued up. Since I didn't find a performance monitor counter to check threads. You'd better generate dump file snapshot to check this. Threads Per Processor Limit only work for classic asp so you shouldn't use it to fix asp.net API issue.

Comment: what is the default max connection limit? can we increase it? How many default concurrent request can be handled by IIS by considering all factors?